# DAX: Why does COUNTROWS with a FILTER defining the table return an error?

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas, business-intelligence, ssas-tabular

I am trying to perform a COUNTROWS on a filtered table where column 'galaxies'[name] = "Milky Way"

Here is my dax measure:

```
test_measure = 
  COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
      'galaxies',
      'galaxies'[name] = "Milky Way"
      )
  )
```

When I run this, I receive an error saying "The expression specified in the query is not a valid table expression".

Why is this an error?  FILTER returns a table and COUNTROWS takes a table as its argument.

Comment: Looks 100% legit. Does this work: `COUNTROWS('galaxies')`?

Comment: Thanks I found the solution on Microsoft board; it is an issue when using Dax studio and how to access the result: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/DAX-Commands-and-Tips/The-expression-specified-in-the-query-is-not-a-valid-table/m-p/889744#M7817

Answer (score 0):

When writing this in Dax Studio, the result from countrows needs to be accessed through a statement; solution found here: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/DAX-Commands-and-Tips/The-expression-specified-in-the-query-is-not-a-valid-table/m-p/889744#M7817

```
DEFINE
test_measure = 
  COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
      'galaxies',
      'galaxies'[name] = "Milky Way"
      )
  )

EVALUATE
ROW("Result",test_measure)
```